# how to prevent JSONP parse from the AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have some code to call couple of other sites (cross domain) with jquery 1.9, which forced me to use jsonp instead of json in an ajax call:

```
.ajax({ 
type : "POST",
url : "http://web.company.com/login/?login_only=1&callback=photos",
data : "user="+ username,
crossDomain : true,  
dataType : "jsonp",
```

However, it always returned a parse error:

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
{"status":1,"redirect":"/cpsess9236070602/web/x3/index.html?login

I know it might because the response is not a jsonp format strictly. How can I capture the redirect variable here without a jsonp error?

Comment: To change json to jsonp you would wrap the json string within photos, so you'd return "photos($jsonString)"

Comment: You can't fix this with client-side javascript. It has to be fixed by `web.company.com`, or you have to use a proxy script on your server.

Comment: @KevinB - Sure you can, if those other sites are running on Node ;) ...

Comment: haha, i guess you're right! making that more precise...

Comment: @KevinB - Anyway, point taken, this can't be solved with the code calling the webservice, it can only be fixed by the webservice, as in they would have to return valid JSONP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the response is not JSONP then there's nothing you can do unless you control the server side.

No parsing actually happens to a JSONP response. A JSONP response is simply a function call with a JavaScript object or array as the argument. jQuery will include the response as a `<script>` tag, executing the JavaScript and so if there is no function call (as such with a regular JSON response) then you can't access the content.

A possible solution could be to proxy the request through a server side script on the same domain as your JavaScript, using a server to server call for the third party, which won't be subject to cross-domain restrictions.